# In cake pattern, how to replace some internal implementation from client side without direct relation?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection

Module code in common-project shared via jar and I wish to change internal dependency **in compile time**

```
trait MyTableNames
trait MyDAO extends MyTableNames
trait ActorService { 
  def send(actorMessage: Any) = println("sending message... will reach some Actor and then from actor to DAO")
}
trait MyActor extends MyDAO
object SaveUserActorMessage

trait MyService extends ActorService {
  def addUser() = send(SaveUserActorMessage) // Not aware of dao just sends a message so service is disconnected from DAO.
}
```

A different server code using common-project via it's shared jar
The client code who uses this service only creates the service.
The problem is that I need to "inject" some other implementation of MyTableNames

from a different project which reuses the common-project above:

```
trait MyOwnTableNames extends MyTableNames 
class MyCustomService extends MyService {
  def someOtherAddUser() = addUser() // How do I tell the DAO which the service does not have a direct reference to, to use MyOwnTableNames, in compile time right now as a client code, I only have reference to MyService.  In addition MyService has no direct relation to MyDAO it's only has a relation to ActorService which has no direct relation to DAO only the end actor which processes the message has a reference to DAO.
}
```

Please note: This example my not look "beautiful" and is not strickly cake pattern, I had to make it so so that I could compact it to a few lines of code, the bottom line is that my client code references a service and does an operation on service, the service then sends a message to actor, and the end actor uses a DAO, my problem is that the DAO at the end is trying to refer to MyTableNames which I want to replace.  I use clean scala code, No DI framework, I prefer to avoid implicits and only use cake pattern if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rely on Scala's linearization to order traits correctly and simply do

```
class MyCustomService extends MyService with MyOwnTableNames
```

There's a small caveat here. If anything that `extend`s `MyTableNames` uses some value of `MyTableNames` in a `val`, you can get an NPE due to class initialization ordering issues. To fix that you would have to either use `lazy val` or `def`.

Comment: Side note: The Scala community has been moving away from the cake pattern over the years. The complexity and rigidity it brings often ends up hurting more than helping.

Comment: Also the brittleness of these NPEs would lead me to recommend just trying out good ol' constructor-based DI.